# Copy .csv files into a .xlsx workbook using python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, csv, macros

I have done extensive researches, however have not been able to come up with the right solution for my needs.

I have python script which generates multiple .csv files.

Each .csv file only has data in column A & B.

Each .csv file has a unique name, and im trying to work out how to copy the .csv file based on its name, into an existing excel workbook, into a specific tab/sheet of the same name.

The .csv files will always be in the same folder.

I would ideally like to use python for this task.

Comment: [try this](http://www.python-excel.org/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
import os
import glob
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
workbook = Workbook('Existing.xlsx')

for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(os.path.splitext(csvfile)[0]) # worksheet with csv file name
    with open(csvfile, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                worksheet.write(r, c, col) # write the csv file content into it
 workbook.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for this, i really appreciate your time spent on answering this query, and the example code provided. I will respond further once i've worked with this example. Thanks again!

Comment: @rajarshi Das I am trying to follow what you did, but for some reason I got the following error message: `Invalid Excel character '[]:*?/\' in sheetname` Do you have any idea why is this happening? thanks

Comment: @newbie that probably means your csv files has one of the following symbols in its title:  `'[]:*?/\'`

Answer (score 1):

using module csv to read data from csv file 
and write .xlsx(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter) with  XlsxWriter  is recommended