# Export CSV files to Excel file in Python (using to_excel)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, export-to-excel, pandas.excelwriter

I want to import the CSV files located in my folder to an Excel file I already had. However, for some reason, I could not make it. There is an error message:

```
Excel worksheet name 'XXXX.csv' must be <= 31 chars 
#(where XXXX is my first CSV file in the folder. It has less than 31 chars)
```

This is my code:

```
for csv_file in allFiles:
    pd.read_csv(csv_file).to_excel(report, sheet_name = csv_file)
```

Where `report` is an Excel file I created previously, `allFiles` is an object that contains all my CSV files (code: `allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")` and `path` is the location where I have my files and it was set up before).

I am using the following libraries:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
from pandas.io.excel import ExcelWriter
```

**PD**: I also tried the following code:

```
with ExcelWriter('report2.xlsx') as ew:    
    for csv_file in allFiles:
        pd.read_csv(csv_file).to_excel(ew, '{}')
```

But It only works for two of the csv files and store all data in just one sheet.

In addition, I tried what it was stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715664/copy-csv-files-into-a-xlsx-workbook-using-python) but an error message appears `Invalid Excel character '[]:*?/\' in sheet name`.

Thanks

Comment: What's the longest worksheet's name (`csv_file`)?

Comment: not excel file. the worksheet in the excel workbook has to have 30 characters or less (if you open a new excel workbook, the sheet names are by default "Sheet 1" "Sheet 2" etc. this name can not have more then 30 characters if you try to rename it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for csv_file in allFiles:
    pd.read_csv(csv_file).to_excel(report, sheet_name = csv_file[:30]) #this will use the first 30 characters of the excel workbook name
```

Comment: It is not working. The longest csv file have an extension in name of 21 charc.